How to add custom significance markers to a boxplot in R using ggsignif?
I am trying to create a boxplot in R with significance markers using ggsignif. For my boxplot, I have two categories ("A" and "B") for each position (1 through 4).
example data:
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(Category = rep(c('A', 'B'), each=200),
                 Position = rep(rep(1:4, each=50), 2),
                 Value = c(rnorm(200, mean=0), rnorm(200, mean=1)))

head(df)
ggplot(df, aes(x=factor(Position), y=Value, fill=Category)) +
    geom_boxplot() +
    labs(x='Position', y='Value', fill='Category') +
    theme_minimal() +
    ggtitle('Boxplot of Values by Position and Category')

I want to label pvalue for each work, assume we have calculated pvalue by a custom function.
Pvalue <- runif(4, min=0, max=0.05)

Note: we cant calculate pvlaue by input value of category A and B, because its based on some background distrubtion evaluated by other data. We cant direct use our custom function with test params in geom_signif function

I have a problem with using significance levels with boxplots. The standard boxplot uses non-parametric location estimates whereas I’m guessing you are constructing these significance values using parametric methods. Your significance calculations should be congruent with your plot.

@IRTFM, We only want to show the difference by boxplot, the significance of the difference is simply obtained by simulation, and we usually identify the method we use in the text. This question may not clear, I have updated it.

Use the annotations argument to manually add the significance bars.
+ geom_signif(
  textsize = 3,
  tip_length=0.01,
  annotations = round(Pvalue, 3),
  y_position = 4, 
  xmin = 0.8 + 0:3, 
  xmax = 1.2 + 0:3
)



You can use the stat_pvalue_manual function from the ggpubr package and the add_xy_position from the rstatix package to do this.
library(ggpubr)
library(rstatix)

stat.test <- df %>%
  group_by(Position) %>%
  wilcox_test(Value ~ Category) %>%
  add_xy_position(x = "Position") %>%

  # Add your custom p-values here
  mutate(p=round(runif(4, 0.01, 0.1), 3))

ggboxplot(df, x = "Position", y = "Value", fill = "Category") + 
   stat_pvalue_manual(stat.test, label = "p", tip.length = 0.01)


